# Fancy indexing in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas.Series object with a hierarchical index consisting of two levels: (code, date). I also have a map {date -> code}. I'd like to get a Series indexed by date only, such that for each date the code is looked up in the provided map and then the pair (code, date) is looked up in the original Series. What's the best way to achieve this in Pandas? 
Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Usually NDFrames (such as Series) are indexed by label. But it is also possible to index an NDFrame by index. That is, you can *index an NDFrame using an Index*!

So, convert the dict to a MultiIndex. Use the MultiIndex to select rows from the
series: `series[index]`.

---

Suppose your series looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(0)

N, M = 3, 5
big_dates = pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=M, freq='D')
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([np.arange(N), big_dates])
series = pd.Series(np.random.randint(10, size=N*M), index=index)
print(series)
# 0  2000-01-01    5
#    2000-01-02    0
#    2000-01-03    3
#    2000-01-04    3
#    2000-01-05    7
# 1  2000-01-01    9
#    2000-01-02    3
#    2000-01-03    5
#    2000-01-04    2
#    2000-01-05    4
# 2  2000-01-01    7
#    2000-01-02    6
#    2000-01-03    8
#    2000-01-04    8
#    2000-01-05    1
# dtype: int64
```

and suppose the dict (let's call it `codemap`) looks like this:

```
dates = pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=N, freq='D')
codes = np.arange(N)
np.random.shuffle(codes)
codemap = dict(zip(dates, codes))
# {Timestamp('2000-01-01 00:00:00', offset='D'): 0,
#  Timestamp('2000-01-02 00:00:00', offset='D'): 1,
#  Timestamp('2000-01-03 00:00:00', offset='D'): 2}
```

then you can form a second MultiIndex out of the `codemap` dict:

```
codemap_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([codemap.values(), codemap.keys()])
```

and use it to index the series:

```
result = series[codemap_index]
# 0  2000-01-01    5
# 1  2000-01-02    3
# 2  2000-01-03    8
# dtype: int64
```

Finally, use droplevel to remove the code level in the index:

```
result.index = result.index.droplevel(0)
print(result)
```

yields

```
2000-01-01    5
2000-01-02    3
2000-01-03    8
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks very much, Ubuntu. What I didn't know is that I could use index to index a Series.